# Почему пишет 'PrefetchDataset' object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, tensorflow

Я сгенерировал дата сет из директории

```
training_dateset = image_dataset_from_directory(
                              'Fruit-Images-Dataset-master/Training',
                              subset='training',
                              seed=42,
                              validation_split=0.1,
                              batch_size=batch_size,
                              image_size=image_size
)
```

Я хочу обработать каждый элемент изображения что бы он лучше читался нейросетью

```
SIZE = 224
def resize_image(img, label):
  img = img.numpy().astype("uint8")
  img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32)
  img = tf.image.resize(img, (SIZE, SIZE)) # изменить размер
  img = img / 255.0 # Переумножить значение что бы оно было равно 0.255
  return img, label
```

Но когда я применяю

train_resized = training_dateset[0].map(resize_image) # Изменить размер каждой картинки

То получаю

> 'PrefetchDataset' object is not subscriptable?

В чем проблема и как это решить?

Comment: Ну значит `training_dateset` не допускает индексирования. Для начала попробуйте преобразовать в список `list(training_dateset)[0]` Хотя и сама конструкция с `.map` тоже выглядит сомнительно.

Comment: @CrazyElf Пишет `'tuple' object has no attribute 'map'` И почему  конструкция с .map выглядит сомнительно? Тогда как лучше всего перевести каждую цветную картинку что бы генератор ее понимал и смог вывести такую же.